# How to create menus like the attached image in Android

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-menu

I want to create an android application in which each menu should seen like the attached image. Is there any possible way to create this types of menus in android..
I am a beginner in android ..if anyone knows how to make this types  of menus.. please give me an example code, it will very helpful for me.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out TabActivity. Or this is what you need to go through http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

For adding menu for an tab you can use ActionBar instead of TabActivity. This will give you an option to add Spinner to the Tab. http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html
But actionBar is available for API level 11 and above.

Comment: Hei Sweety, thank you for your reply. I think Fixed Tab is suited for creating my page like inthe given image, but my need is ,when a user touches a tab it will switch to next view also a drop down menu will appear. how can do it??